# mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpython"

Tags: python, gcc, swig

Excuse my newbiness. I have been trying to extend python with c for days now. there are lots of methods and none of them are Windows-friendly. Currently I am trying to follow this SWIG tutorial(buttom of the page).https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Extending_with_C#Using_SWIG

I've reached the last step where I should link everything to python, but when I write the command

```
 `gcc -shared hellomodule.o hello_wrap.o -o _hello.so -lpython`
```

I get this error
"c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpython"

I've tried:

- adding python as an environmental variable
- copying python address to the link command  as follows

`gcc -shared hellomodule.o hello_wrap.o -o _hello.so -lC:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32`

any help would be REALLY appreciated

Comment: It looks like you are (a) mixing 32 bit python with a 64 bit compiler and (b) not naming your Python library correctly, Does `C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32` contain any file named `libpython.dll` or `libpython.lib` or `libpython.so`? I don't think this is the case on Windows.  They usually name their libraries without the `lib` prefix. If so, you need to provide a full path to the library and not any `-l` flag (look up what it does).

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. you are right, seems like I have got 32 bit python for some reason. I will reinstall the 64 bit ones. but How should I name my "python library"?

Comment: *you need to provide a full path to the library*

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. there is a python3.dll , python39.dll and a lib folder which in return contains many other folders and files

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. and there is a dll library

Comment: Try passing `-L c:\whatever -lpython39` to gcc. If it does not work, try `c:\whatever\python39.dll` without any `-l` or `-L`.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Now I am getting alot like these

lo_wrap.o:hello_wrap.c:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_Dealloc'
hello_wrap.o:hello_wrap.c:(.text+0xc38): undefined reference to `__imp_PyUnicode_AsUTF8'
hello_wrap.o:hello_wrap.c:(.text+0xc57): undefined reference to `__imp_PyUnicode_FromString'
hello_wrap.o:hello_wrap.c:(.text+0xcaa): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_MemoryError'
hello_wrap.o:hello_wrap.c:(.text+0xcbd): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_IOError'

Comment: I recommend asking a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for `libpython.so`, which you won't find on Windows.  In general, Python extensions on Windows must be built with the same compiler that built Python, so that the runtime libraries match up, and that's almost always Visual Studio.  Check here for details:

https://docs.python.org/3/extending/windows.html

If you have a Mingw build of Python, then you're going in the right direction.  If not, then you'll need Visual Studio.

Comment: I guess Mingw builds for python doesn't work well with 64 bit, I am sorry this may sound dumb but what will I need Visual studio for exactly?, because I already have(but not using it for this proj).

Comment: MinGW uses VC runtime. There is nothing wrong with mixing it with VC, people are doing it all the time. (As a C compiler, not C++).